# Вопросительное и восклицательное предожение — какой знак поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется вот такое предложение: "Что с ним происходит, подскажите". Первая часть предложения, до запятой, явно вопросительная, но на конце стоит восклицательный призыв. Так какой знак нужно ставить? Вопросительный, восклицательный или оба сразу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ввиду того что появилось сказуемое *"подскажите"*, слово *"что"* стало подчинительным союзом. Следовательно, перед нами сложноподчиненное предложение В главной его части (*"подскажите"*) вопроса нет, следовательно, ставим либо точку, либо восклицательный знак. 
Кстати, ещё здесь хорошо бы смотрелось тире вместо запятой, но, впрочем, запятая тоже допустима.

---

Отчасти я согласен с [[@Соан](/users/169/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BD)](/users/169/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BD), но лишь отчасти. У правила, которое было им приведено как доказательство, есть примечание:

> Если придаточное предложение образует косвенный вопрос, то в конце сложноподчиненного предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится, например: Не знаю, сколько времени я пробыл в этом положении (Л Толстой); Ты не сказала нам, почему не ходишь в училище (Федин). Постановка вопросительного знака после предложения с косвенным вопросом встречается, если последний содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, например: Не понимаю, что тебе нужно? (Чехов); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (Горький).

Так что выбор теперь зависит от того, как мы обзовем этот вопрос: косвенным или прямым. Из-за инверсии это становится довольно трудным, поэтому, я считаю, можно сказать: пусть автор сам решает.

Comment: А мне кажется, что в этом случае придаточное и образует косвенный вопрос: подскажите (что?). Не понимаю, что в моем ответе не так.

Comment: Думаю, только то, что возможны обе трактовки. А Вы не совсем четко и недостаточно обосновали свою. В частности - тезис о том, что здесь именно прямой вопрос. В примере из Чехова случай проще, хотя фраза более сложная. Фрагмент "какое ему дело" просто невозможно в контексте трактовать как самостоятельное придаточное, поэтому то, что это прямой вопрос, сомнения не вызывает.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это сложноподчиненное предложение. Следовательно, "вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если придаточное предложение содержит в себе прямой вопрос, например: Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему дело? (Чехов)". См. Д. Розенталь, §76.
В нашем случае  придаточное предложение содержит в себе прямой вопрос: "Что с ним происходит?"

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, мы имеем дело со случаем, когда смысловая нагрузка на основное и подчиненное предложение может не совпадать с грамматической. Более того, грамматика здесь неочевидна, а акценты смысла может указать только автор.

Рассуждать (предполагать) автор может так:

~1. Здесь действительно прямой вопрос, а "подскажите" на самом деле не является основным предложением, в выполняет роль вводное, что-то типа словесного эрзаца "пожалуйста" а то и просто слова-паразита. Тогда вопросительный вполне уместен, возможно даже вопросительный с восклицательным (интересно, почему нет короткого названия у этого "двойного" знака?).

~2. Предложение сложноподчиненное в полном смысле, но вопрос прямой и заключается он как раз в основном предложении. Сравните: "Подскажите, как добраться...?" Несмотря на повелительное наклонение, предложение выражает неуверенность в способности спрашиваемого дать нужный ответ. Случай, согласен, несколько искусственный, но все же возможный, вопросительный знак тут без вариантов. Сам по себе или в сочетании с вопросительным.

~3. Нет здесь прямого вопроса. Есть просьба пояснить, т.е. вопрос максимум - косвенный. 
Сравните: "посмотрите, что с ним происходит!"
Тогда - восклицательный. Просто точка, вроде бы, не подходит, все-таки при таком варианте тут явное повелительное наклонении без всяких оговорок. Хотя, возможно, кто-то и точку сможет обосновать.

При прочих равных я бы все-таки предпочел последний вариант, т.е. трактовал бы как просьбу, а не вопрос, со всеми вытекающими. И ставил бы таким образом восклицательный знак. Но, повторюсь, это зависит от авторских акцентов.

Answer (score 0):

Меня очень смущает дискуссия о различных подходах к интонационной и смысловой инт ерпретации данного предложения. Думаю, что здесь явное сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором главное стоит на втором месте. Если в конце предложения поставить вопросительный знак, то надо менять окончание глагола и записывать его как "подскажете": "Что с ним происходит, подскажете?". Можно согласиться с вопросительным знаком (и то со скрипом), если главное предложение разместить впереди: "Подскажите, что с ним происходит?" Но в том виде, как оно представлено в вопросе, это явно побудительное предложение с повествовательной интонацией

Comment: >Если в конце предложения поставить вопросительный знак, то надо менять окончание глагола...

Виктор, но ко мнению-то Розенлаля уж как минимум надо прислушаться. 
Именно в таком понимании грамматики и синтаксиса: "вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если придаточное предложение содержит в себе прямой вопрос". Т.е. если уж спорить, то с применимостью данной рекомендации в конкретном случае. Ну или о различных подходах к тому, что вы назвали "интонационной и смысловой интерпретацией". Хотя на самом деле это как раз грамматика.